# Joomla page title is not article title for some articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, seo, category-blog, metadata

I am using version `3.6.5`. After some SEO inspection, we realized that some article pages are using duplicate page titles (the site name being the page title).

I compared the article whose page title was the site title with another article which was displaying the article title as page title, all the settings seems to be the same except the actual contents.

Can someone tell me why the discrepancy in displaying the page titles for the same setting article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a menu item pointing directly to an article, then the page title can be set at the menu item level. Additionally, there are some SEO tools (such as sh404SEF) that will allow you to set the browser title of each link.

Answer (score 2):

I found the resolution for my case, it was simple, I just didn't notice. The articles that didn't display the Article title as the Page title, they didn't have the `Itemid=XXX` parameter on their URLs.